# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'delete_url' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['delete_url/(?P<web>[0-9]+)\\Z']

Tags: django, django-urls, django-url-reverse

Hi I'm getting an error when I run my code. I am trying to create a delete function on my webpage.

Thank you for your time.

My code is as follows:

home.html : error is in the href tag

```
{% for web in webs_list %}
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                {{web.url.id}}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{web.url.website}}
                                <a href="{% url 'delete-url' web.id %}" >
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                </a>
                                <div class="space" ></div>
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updateModal" >Update</button>
                            </td>
                            {% if web.status == "True"  %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-success">Up</a> </td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-danger">Down</a> </td>
                            {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add_url',views.add_url,name='add-url'),
    path('search_url',views.search_url,name='search-url'),
    # path('update_url',views.update_url),
    path('delete_url/<int:web>',views.delete_url,name="delete_url"),
]
```

views.py

```
def delete_url(request,web):
    url = Website.objects.get(pk=web)
    url.delete()
    return redirect('monitor/home.html')
```

models.py

```
class Website(models.Model):
    website = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Comment: Try Mentioning app name with `delete_url` in `<a href>`

Comment: Also share the view which is rendering this delete template.

Comment: @Uniquedesign you mean my home.html?

Comment: @meister are you using `app_name` in your `urls.py` file?

Comment: @Mubasharjaved no, but my redirecting works for all my other urls

Comment: @meister try changing your delete url name and replace the underscore with a hyphen like this `name='delete-url'`.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved i'm still getting the same error :(.. is it because of my for loop in the html? i've updated my urls.py code in the question

Comment: have you updated your `html` file with the updated url-name too?

Comment: try **printing**  `web.id` in your **html** file because the exception says that Django tried to find a URL with an empty string argument.

Comment: @Mubasharjaved yes i have.. still getting the same error.. :<

Comment: Make sure the id, whether it is an int or str.

Comment: Also change pk to id in `Website.objects.get`. I am sure there's no field named as pk in your models.

Answer (score 0):

**1-option**

*Edit your urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'your_app_name'
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add_url',views.add_url,name='add-url'),
    path('search_url',views.search_url,name='search-url'),
    # path('update_url',views.update_url),
    path('delete_url/<int:web>',views.delete_url,name="delete_url"),
```

*Edit your .html*

```
{% for web in webs_list %}
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                {{web.url.id}}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{web.url.website}}
                                <a href="{% url 'your_app_name:delete-url' web.id %}" >
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                </a>
                                <div class="space" ></div>
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updateModal" >Update</button>
                            </td>
                            {% if web.status == "True"  %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-success">Up</a> </td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-danger">Down</a> </td>
                            {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

**2-option**

*Edit your urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add_url',views.add_url,name='add-url'),
    path('search_url',views.search_url,name='search-url'),
    # path('update_url',views.update_url),
    path('delete_url/<int:pk>',views.delete_url,name="delete_url"),
```

*Edit your views.py*

```
def delete_url(request,pk):
    url = Website.objects.get(id=pk)
    url.delete()
    return redirect('monitor/home.html')
```

**3-option**

*Edit your urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('add_url',views.add_url,name='add-url'),
    path('search_url',views.search_url,name='search-url'),
    # path('update_url',views.update_url),
    path('r'^delete_url/(?P<oid>[0-9]+)/$'',views.delete_url,name="delete_url"),
```

*Edit your .html*

```
{% for web in webs_list %}
                            <tr>
                            <th scope="row">
                                {{web.url.id}}
                            </th>
                            <td>
                                {{web.url.website}}
                                <a href="{% url 'your_app_name:delete-url' oid = web.id %}" >
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                                </a>
                                <div class="space" ></div>
                                <button type="button" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#updateModal" >Update</button>
                            </td>
                            {% if web.status == "True"  %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-success">Up</a> </td>
                            {% else %}
                            <td> <a class="btn btn-danger">Down</a> </td>
                            {% endif %}
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: or try to cast to string your ```delete_url``` path, like ```path('delete_url/<str:pk>',views.delete_url,name="delete_url")```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the `web` variable has a value in the template.
Are you sure you are passing a not null web value in the calling view context ?
Maybe you can post the calling view code

Answer (score -1):

at the href: "{% url 'delete-url' id=web.id %}"

Comment: The syntax was correct, you do not specify id= in template url tags

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).